Trying to create Mosaic Dataset in ArcGIS Pro but it is greyed out
I am trying to create a Mosaic Dataset in ArcGIS Pro 3.3 but it is greyed out.

Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. If your Question does not span several paragraphs, it is likely to be closed. Please [Edit] the Question to explain where you are in the UI when this option is disabled (Hint: It has to be in a geodatabase workspace). A screenshot would not be inappropriate.

And also include your ArGIS license level in your edit.
